# Laravel Socialite: This authorization code has been used (Facebook)

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

**Description:** I have implemented the laravel socialite stateless, because I am using Laravel as a backend app with REST APIs and my frontend is in Angular. I get the correct redirect URL, however, when I enter my Facebook credentials and agree to proceed with the application I get redirected to my site with the following issue:

```
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":36009,"f (truncated...)
```

Here are the routes in my **api.php**

```
Route::get('/auth/redirect/{provider}', [AuthController::class, 'redirectToProvider'])
    ->where('provider', '[A-Za-z]+');
Route::get('/auth/{provider}/callback', [AuthController::class, 'handleProviderCallback'])
    ->where('provider', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

And the following functions in my controller **AuthController.php**

```
/**
     * @param $provider
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function redirectToProvider($provider): JsonResponse
    {
        $response = $this->authService->redirectToProvider($provider);
        return response()->json($response);
    }

    /**
     * @param $provider
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws \App\Exceptions\Custom\CustomValidationException
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider, Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        ValidationUtils::validate($request->all(), [
            'code' => 'required',
        ]);

        $response = $this->authService->handleProviderCallback($provider);
        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

And this is where it resolves in the **AuthServiceImpl.php**

```
/**
     * @param $provider
     * @return array[]
     */
    public function redirectToProvider($provider): array
    {
        if (!in_array($provider, self::PROVIDERS)) {
            throw new CustomNotFoundException(trans('errors.not_found.provider'));
        }

        $success['provider_redirect'] = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();

        return [
            'data' => $success
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param $provider
     * @return array[]|void
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        if (!in_array($provider, self::PROVIDERS)) {
            throw new CustomNotFoundException(trans('errors.not_found.provider'));
        }

        try {
            $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

            if ($providerUser) {
                $user = $this->socialAccountsService->findOrCreate($providerUser, $provider);
                $user->markEmailAsVerified();
                $token = $user->createToken(env('API_AUTH_TOKEN_PASSPORT_SOCIAL'))->accessToken;

                return [
                    'data' => [
                        'tokens' => [
                            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                            'expires_in' => 5400,
                            'access_token' => $token
                        ],
                        'user' => new UserResource($user)
                    ],
                    'message' => trans('auth.login')
                ];
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CustomUnauthorizedException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

You can try it yourself by logging in with Facebook on the following link: https://afillix.common.mk/login

[image]

Comment: The `redirect_uri` specified in your login dialog call, is `https://afillix.common.mk/login/social/facebook` - I don't see how that is supposed to match the routing configuration you have shown?

Comment: @CBroe well that is because the front end runs on afilix.common.mk, and the backend is on api.common.mk - so that is why the redirect_uri is set the frontend url, and from the frontend once you hit that page it makes a call to the following backend api: api.common.mk/auth/facebook/callback?code={CODE}

Comment: I have went down to comment all the lines in the handleProviderCallback() function and it appears that the line where I am getting the $providerUser is causing the issue.. any idea why that may be? @CBroe